# Using Unique IDs as Input

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

Table **Users** has unique `USERNAME` values.

Table **Roles** has unique `ROLENAME` values.

I need to write a script that joins the 2 in a **USER_TO_ROLE** table:

```
INSERT INTO USER_TO_ROLE
  (user_id,
   role_id)
VALUES
  (SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username=@username LIMIT 1,
   SELECT id FROM Roles WHERE rolename=@rolename LIMIT 1);
```

MySQL Workbench gives Error Code 1064:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id from Users where username=@username LIMIT 1, select record_id' at line 3

Is there a way to write that so that I don't have to make 2 separate database calls, writing the id values down, before making the insert?

**RESOLVED**

Using [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)'s example, I wrote this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO USER_TO_ROLE
  (user_id,
   role_id)
SELECT u.id, r.id
FROM Users u JOIN Roles r
WHERE u.username=@username and r.rolename=@rolename;
```

I had to take **VALUES** out for the **INSERT** statement to work.

Comment: You can't do that.  Use a transaction and two separate calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have 2 `SELECT` clauses in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query.

You may rewrite your query to

```
INSERT INTO USER_TO_ROLE
  (user_id,
   role_id)
  SELECT 
    (SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username=@username LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT id FROM Roles WHERE rolename=@rolename LIMIT 1)
```

That way you would have a single `SELECT` with 2 nested queries correspondingly.

Comment: That's cool. Does that require a certain version? It's giving me `unexpected SELECT_SYM, expecting '('` on the new **SELECT**.